# Folder protected with htaccess password is now hidden in directory listing?

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, hidden, .htpasswd

I noticed that when I protect a folder with a password it hides it from directory index listings. This is undesirable but is it avoidable?

Here is the code I am using in the root dir (which is password protected too)

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/documents/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
<limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>

<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options +Indexes
IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble
IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name
HeaderName /documents/header.html
 ReadmeName /documents/footer.html
IndexIgnore header.html phpinfo.php footer.html logo.png favicon.ico .htaccess .ftpquota .DS_Store icons *.log *,v *,t .??* *~ *#
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In 'nix OSs, the leading period makes the directory hidden by default. What build are you using? In Ubunutu, there is an option in Nautlius to show hidden files for a folder.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I am running CentOS 5